# how to sort dictionary based on keys, while also printing out the values in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

This is my dictionary

```
x = {'balance': 19.1, 'advance': 0.4, 'withdrawal': 53.0, 'deposit': 24.7, 'transfer': 2.8000000000000003}
```

when i try to sort it by

```
sorted(x) = ['advance', 'balance', 'deposit', 'transfer', 'withdrawal']
```

it only gave me the keys, i also need the corresponding values with it

Comment: `sorted(x.items())`...

Comment: but how do i change it into a list?

Comment: That **is** a list. A list with `(key, value)` tuples.

Comment: what i got is in the form of dictionary like this. {'withdrawal': 53.0, 'balance': 19.1, 'advance': 0.4, 'deposit': 24.7, 'transfer': 2.8000000000000003}

Comment: actually, thanks i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {'balance': 19.1, 'advance': 0.4, 'withdrawal': 53.0, 'deposit': 24.7, 'transfer': 2.8000000000000003}
print [i for i in sorted(x.items())]
```

Output:`[('advance', 0.4), ('balance', 19.1), ('deposit', 24.7), ('transfer', 2.8000000000000003), ('withdrawal', 53.0)]`